# Deploying VUE Js Application to Heroku issues (404 not found - blank page after deploy)

Tags: vue.js, heroku, deployment

I am having a hard time getting my app to come up on Heroku after deploying a VUE JS application. It keeps giving me a Not Found page (even when everything builds)

Answer (score 0):

After looking over a lot of suggestions on Stack Overflow and videos, I finally figured it out. The first think you want to do is go to the command line and type: Heroku Logs, when I did this, I saw this:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'
After some research, I found out that when the vue cli builds, it places it assets in a folder called 'dist" and not build. In my server.js file, I just changed my entry to

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
{
//Set static folder (our public folder)
app.use(express.static('client/dist'));
app.get('*',(req,res) => {
       res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'client','dist','index.html')); 
})
```

}

It "used to have" 'build' in it, 'build' is actually used if you are deploying a "React" application (which have done on a previous build). After I changed this to 'dis', MY APP CAME UP .. !!! YAHHHHH!!!